# Bukkit how to store data

Tags: bukkit

Hi I was wondering how could I possibly store player data? do I need a extra class? Do I need a certain code? I'm not sure how to do this, and if anyone could help that would be appreciated! I want to store data so if a player picks a kit they can't pick another one.

Comment: You mean you want to Write in a file for example 'playername: kitname' ?

Comment: Yes so I can detect if they can use another kit or not.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store what kit a user is using for temporary storage you can use a Map with the player's UUID and kit. For example `Map<UUID, Kit> userKits = new HashMap<UUID, Kit>();` assuming your kit has it's own object. Then when they try to pick another just check if they are in the Map and if they are send them a message if not add them.

If you want more permanent storage you will need to store this in a file.

Comment: Basically I want to make it so a player can pick a kit, only pick one, and if they die then they can pick another one, I'm thinking I need a listener for PlayerDeathEvent but would I need a certain class for the hashmap/map?

Comment: You would indeed need to listen for deaths. Once they die remove them from the map. No, you would not need a certain class for it, it can go in any class. Just make sure to not static abuse.

Answer (score -3):

So simply you are saying that when a player picks a kit they will not be able to pick a kit again unless they die. A simple solution to this is to store it in an Array. I personally use Arraylists so that I can store data for each player at any time.

So for example. You want to create a new Arraylist called kitTrue, you will need to use this method.

```
ArrayList<Player> kitTrue = new ArrayList<Player>();
```

Then simply to store the player inside the arraylist. This is a good method to use simply because you can remove the player on death events and leave events. When the player has simply chosen the kit you can add them to the arraylist. When they die or logout they will be removed from the arraylist.

To remove player from Arraylist:

```
kitTrue.remove(p);
```

To add player to Arraylist:

```
kitTrue.add(p);
```

So here is an example on how you would remove the player on death and quit event.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e){
    Player p = (Player) e.getEntity();
    kitTrue.remove(p);  
}
@EventHandler
public void onLogout(PlayerQuitEvent e){
    Player p = (Player) e.getPlayer();
    kitTrue.remove(p);  
}
```

So when a player chooses the kit this could be an option on how you would execute it. Could look something like this. But you will get the idea. This is how you would add a player to the arraylist.

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String   label, String[] args) {
    Player p = (Player) sender;
    if(cmd.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("kit")){
        if(args.length == 0){
            p.sendMessage("§7You have chosen the kit.");
            archer(p);
            kitTrue.add(p);
        } else{
            p.sendMessage("§7Usage§8: §b/kit");
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

Next you want to identify if the player has already chosen a kit. There are many ways on how to setup this system but I will just show you the basics of how it all works. So hope you get the idea.

```
@Override
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    Player p = (Player) sender;
    if(cmd.getLabel().equalsIgnoreCase("kit")){
        if(args.length == 0){
            if(kitTrue.contains(p)){
                p.sendMessage("§7You have already chosen a kit this life.");
            }
            p.sendMessage("§7You have chosen the kit.");
            archer(p);
            kitTrue.add(p);
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
```

So why should you choose arraylists? Well Arraylists have the ability to store single values such as players and strings etc. You can simply check if the arraylist has the player or string in the list and then you can run a code saying that the player is inside the list or identify if the player doesn't exist inside the array. Very easy and have always used this. I hope that this is something that you are looking for.

Thx Pixl

Comment: Why use a player's object when you can use their UUID?

Comment: You can use either and I know that UUID is a better way to identify the player but it really doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually it does. You are not stressing at all **why removing the player from the list on disconnect** is important. Player objects unlike UUID's hold chunks loaded if not removed on disconnect so that is a great RAM leak. 
Now, as far as the rest of the code is concerned, it is not great. First of all you abuse casting, its not logical to cast Player to Player. It is equally unlogical to cast **sender** to **Player** without being sure it is actually a Player instance. Don't belive me? Run the command /kit through console and find out yourself.